# Adding a margin messing up display of drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, cluster-computing, margin

The issue I'm having is that when I add a `margin` to my hover over drop down navmenu it messes up all the content which was meant to drop down and clusters it all up nearly just above it. Although before adding a `margin` the navigation menu worked perfectly fine, and yes removing the `margin` fixes the issue but I need to add a `margin`.

Here is my CSS, let me know if you need the HTML also. (Note, I am doing this on Notepad++ as HTML >4<)

```
#navmenu a {                                                        
    text-decleration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 124px;
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: ;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    font-family: Magneto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: ffffff;
    transition: ease-in all 400ms;                        
    -moz-transition: ease-in all 300ms;                                                 
    -webkit-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
    -o-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
    margin: -40px;
}

#navmenucontainer {
    margin: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 230px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;            
}
```

Here is the Relevent HTML:

```
  <div id="navmenucontainer">
    <ul id="navmenu">
    <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ThursdayWebsites2/Education.html">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ThursdayWebsites2/Hobbies.html">Interests</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/fajLeLsy/

it looks like you want to do something like this

don't give `-margin` for `a`

```css
#navmenu a {
  text-decleration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 124px;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: ;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Magneto;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: ffffff;
}
#navmenucontainer {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 230px;
  height: auto;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
ul li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: ease-in all 400ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
  -o-transition: ease-in all 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="navmenucontainer">
  <ul id="navmenu">
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Education</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">Interests</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```